# How can I view another form when all PictureBox are visible in VB - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Im creating a simple math game for kids using VB in Visual Studio 2010. Following is the code

```
Public Class HSone

    Private Sub HSone_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Form Properties
        Me.ControlBox = False
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.Text = ""
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(907, 574)

        'On load Hide Objects
        PictureBox1.Visible = False
        PictureBox2.Visible = False
        PictureBox3.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        PictureBox1.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click
        PictureBox3.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_MouseHover(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.MouseHover, Label2.MouseHover, Label1.MouseHover
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    End Sub

End Class
```

How can I view the next form when all picturebox are now visible?
Thanks!

Comment: i recommend to create array of picture boxes and check in for loop

Comment: Form2.Show() or Form2.ShowDialog()

Comment: @JackGajanan Thanks. but how can i do that? can you show me some sample code?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I know i can use that. can you show me some code but it will check if all the pictureboxes are visible then i can use Form2.Show()

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: And this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx

Comment: I already fixed it by adding this sub on click events. :)


Private Sub CheckAndMoveOn()
        If PictureBox1.Visible = True AndAlso PictureBox2.Visible = True AndAlso PictureBox3.Visible = True Then
            Dim frm As New Form2
            Form2.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub